# How to define a concrete type constructor inside a generic class

Tags: java, generics

Trying to define a concrete type constructor inside a generic class, but got the following errors. Anyone knows how to fix this? Thanks.

```
public class GenericStack<E>{
    private java.util.ArrayList<E> list=new java.util.ArrayList<>();

    public GenericStack(String a){
            this.push(a);
    }
    public int getSize(){
            return list.size();
    }

    public E peek(){
            return list.get(getSize()-1);
    }

    public void push(E o){
            list.add(o);
    }

    public E pop(){
            E o=list.get(getSize()-1);
            list.remove(getSize()-1);
            return o;
    }

    boolean isEmpety(){
            return list.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
            return "Stack"+list.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
            GenericStack<String> stack1=new GenericStack<>("testmessage");

            System.out.println(stack1);
    }

}
```

Get the following error:

```
GenericStack.java:6: error: incompatible types: String cannot be   converted to E
    this.push(a);
              ^
where E is a type-variable:
E extends Object declared in class GenericStack
```

Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

Comment: Why do you have a generic collection if you always put a string there?

Comment: First of all, constructors are for initialization, only. Don't add to the stack in the constructor. Second, `LinkedList` already supports `push`, `pop`, and the other operations. Third, `isEmpety` is almost certainly not the method name you want. Most important, if you're writing a generic class, don't write a specialization of the generics into the same class. That's bad.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to define a constructor for a stack containing strings, you can't. Constructors and other instance methods have to work for all types within the type variable's bounds.

But you can define a static factory method which only creates instances of `GenericStack<String>`:

```
static GenericStack<String> create(String e) {
  GenericStack<String> s = new GenericStack<>();
  s.push(e);
  return s;
}
```

Comment: But this function, if inside the above class, would sill suffer the error of converting E to String type, isn't that still a problem?

Comment: No, that is not a problem, because the "conversion" you imagine happening doesn't.

Comment: @Charles no: static methods don't belong to instances of the class, so they are not constrained by the type variables of an instance.

Comment: Can I understand it as a generic type must be passed into a generic type member, but never passed into a concrete typed member, even though the generic type actually stands for may be the same as that concrete type?

Answer (score 1):

Define your constructor parameter to match the type defined for the class

```
public GenericStack(E a) {
```